# ¿Cómo pasar la suma de una seleccion a un insert into en sql server?

Tags: sql-server

El caso es el siguiente, tengo que hacer que la suma de un `select` el cual lo igualo a una variable pueda insertarla en una `table`,el problema es que al ejecutarlo el código como `stored procedure` me devuelve un error como si estuviera vacía la variable. ¿Alguna solución?
(O en su defecto una manera de mantener el valor en la variable,que eso me ayudaria mas)

```
 create database ejemplo
go
use ejemplo
go

create table inventario(
id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
nombre varchar(40)not null unique,
modelo varchar(30) not null,
descripcion varchar(80) not null,
precio decimal(5,2) not null,
cantidad int not null,
marca varchar(30) not null
)
go


create procedure spAgregarInventario
@nom varchar(40),
@mod varchar(30),
@desc varchar(80),
@precio decimal(5,2),
@cant int,
@marca varchar(30)
as
insert into inventario(nombre,modelo,descripcion,precio,cantidad,marca)
values(@nom,@mod,@desc,@precio,@cant,@marca)
go

exec spAgregarInventario 'ejemplo','ejemplo','ejemplo',10,100,'ejemplo'
go


create table venta(
id_venta int not null primary key identity(1,1),
idinventario int not null foreign key (idinventario)references inventario(id),
cantidad int not null,
pagar decimal(5,2) not null,
fecha datetime
)
go

create trigger tr_venta
on venta for insert
as
update inventario set inventario.cantidad=inventario.cantidad - inserted.cantidad
from inserted inner join inventario on inventario.id=inserted.idinventario
go

--Precisamente aqui.
create procedure spAgregarVenta
@idinventario int,
@cantidad int
as
begin
declare @pagofinal decimal(5,2)
select @pagofinal=sum(ve.cantidad*inv.precio)
from venta ve inner join inventario inv on ve.idinventario=inv.id
insert into venta(idinventario,cantidad,pagar,fecha)values(@idinventario,@cantidad,@pagofinal,GETDATE())
end
go

exec spAgregarVenta 1,10
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Dentro de todo el código que publicas, ¿dónde está el error? Te invito a hacer el [tour], a leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y de paso de una vez como crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que, para cuando haces la consulta, con el *select*, la primera vez, no existe ningún registro en la tabla.

Además sospecho que lo que quieres almacenar allí es el valor de *esa* venta, por lo tanto, no hay ningún *join* que practicar y ningún `sum()` que hacer. Debes recuperar un solo registro de la tabla (para obtener el precio) y multiplicarlo por la cantidad que estás recibiendo como parámetro, diría que debe quedar algo en la línea de:

```
create procedure spAgregarVenta
  @idinventario int,
  @cantidad int
as
begin
  declare @pagofinal decimal(10, 2);
  select @pagofinal = @cantidad *inv.precio
    from inventario inv 
   where inv.idinventario = @idinventario;

  insert into venta(idinventario, cantidad, pagar, fecha)
  values(@idinventario, @cantidad, @pagofinal, GETDATE());
end
go
```

Finalmente, solo agregaría el hecho de que estás utilizando un campo muy limitado para los precios y aún más para las cantidades. Decimal(5,2) puede almacenar como máximo `999.99`.  Cantidad es un entero, que puede almacenar números en el orden de miles de millones de unidades, y *pagar* es la multiplicación de ambos. Con una venta a un precio de `100.00` de solo `100` unidades, el total a pagar es de `10,000.00`, por lo que será imposible almacenarla.

Comment: Pues a funcionado a la perfeccion,muchas gracias,aunque le hice uno que otro cambio menor que me supongo que se te habra pasado,al final escribi esto:

alter procedure spAgregarVenta
@.idinventario int,
@.cantidad int
as
begin
declare @.pagofinal decimal(10, 2)
  select @.pagofinal = @.cantidad *precio
    from inventario
   where id=@.idinventario

insert into venta(idinventario,cantidad,pagar,fecha)values(@idinventario,@cantidad,@pagofinal,GETDATE())
end
go


Todo bien,solo que ahora me doy cuenta que mi trigger no funciona..Aun asi muchas gracias :D

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. El código lo escribí aquí mismo en el explorador y mi objetivo, más que una sintaxis perfecta, es dar la idea de la solución. Sobre el trigger, podrías hacer una nueva pregunta si lo consideras necesario. Tu pregunta original no hablaba sobre eso, ni es válido hacer varias preguntas en una. Un saludo.

Comment: Si,justamente estaba redactando una nueva pregunta relacionada al problema con el trigger,gracias nuevamente ^^

Comment: Bueno..ya descubri cual era el problema con el trigger...
No lo habia creado y solo lo tenia en mi hoja de trabajo..

Comment: Excelente, felicitaciones!